# Segue from the MasterViewController in a SplitViewController to another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `SplitViewController` with a `UITableViewController` as the masterViewController and a `UIViewController` as the detailViewController.

[image]

[image]

When the user taps a cell, I need to push to a new `UITableViewController`. So I added a segue from the cell to a `UITableViewController`. But what happens is the `UITableViewController` gets added to the masterViewController's stack.

[image]

How can I push to a whole new `UITableViewController` from the masterViewController?

Comment: This seems like the correct behavior - you push = you add VC to the VC stack. So what do you want to do, replace?

Comment: That's right. Simply push to a whole new view controller, not just in the masterViewController.

Comment: Like the *whole split view controller*? Aka the whole screen should push new screen?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you are wishing to show some extra information about what is in the master view cells, why not use a popover segue. This will present your table in a popover which will look better IMHO on an iPad and also work on an iPhone. If you actually wish to do a full iPad sized table view, you will need to use a modal segue to the controller. In both cases if you plan to push controllers on to your shown table view your will need to present a UINavigationController with your new table view as the root. If you use a modal, you will need to provide a Done button so you can get back to the split view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! First I should mention Michal's answer helped me to get an idea and point me in the right direction so thanks to him.

What I did was simple actually. Before I had a View Controller with a container view embedding the split view controller. I simply went ahead and embedded that view controller in a navigation controller.

[image]

Then I added the view controller I want to segue to in the storyboard but no segue attached to it. I'm doing it programatically in the masterViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
if let rootVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let mapVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapVC") as! UIViewController
    rootVC.showViewController(mapVC, sender: nil)
}
```

I get a reference to the rootViewController which is a navigation controller through the AppDelegate and I push the new view controller I want to it's stack.

That's it! Here's a demo [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct94a71656txgod/test.zip?dl=0) in case anyone's interested.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example how I approach such functionality (I created a new *Master-Detail Application*):

**Storyboard:**
[image]

Notice that the root VC is now a `UINavigationController`. Therefore `AppDelegate` must be changed accordingly:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let navCtr = self.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController

    let splitViewController = navCtr.visibleViewController as UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

And then finally in `MasterViewController` add this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: nil)
    } else {
        let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        if let let rootCtr = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
            let newSplit = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitVC") as UISplitViewController

            /// Because of Apple's "Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller" 
            let yetAnotherNavCtr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newSplit)
            rootCtr.presentViewController(newSplit, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Important notes:**

1. If you create new *MasterDetail Application* from the template, you **have to** disconnect the `showDetail` segue, because it is directly linked to the cell's `selected` callback. If you want to preserve that functionality as well, simply connect it again not from the cell itself, but from the whole VC. To be able to use it as in my funky `didSelect...` method that performs the `showDetail` segue on even rows.
2. The Split View presentation will work only once - I haven't implemented the whole rootViewController replacement - the *lldb* will complain saying: `Attempt to present UISplitViewController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` if you'll try to do it for the second time. But that's really up to your requirements for how you want the app to behave.
3. Name the SplitView Controller in `Storyboard` "SplitVC" (Storyboard ID) if you want to present the Split View Controller like I am doing in my code.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I tried it myself but I can't seem to get it to work. I followed all the steps you've mentioned. But the cells aren't clickable. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gksn7bol2s07c9n/MasterDetail.zip?dl=0)'s what I've done so far. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I finally did it! Your answer sure helped. I posted my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30176623/1077789).